# postgresql multiple Common Table Expressions

Tags: postgresql

I have to tables : *mutation* and *ann_commune*. The colums *code_postal* and *id_commune* are in *ann_commune*, all the other ones in *mutation*.

I need to get together the average for the top 3 values of several departments

```
         WITH six as ( 
    SELECT commune as commune_six, AVG(valeur_fonciere) as moyenne_six 
    FROM mutation
        LEFT JOIN ann_commune    on mutation.id_commune = ann_commune.id_commune
      WHERE code_postal LIKE '06%'
      GROUP BY commune_six
      ORDER BY moyenne_six DESC
      LIMIT 3
    ),
    treize as ( 
    SELECT commune as commune_treize, AVG(valeur_fonciere) as moyenne_treize 
    FROM mutation
        LEFT JOIN ann_commune    on mutation.id_commune = ann_commune.id_commune
      WHERE code_postal LIKE '13%'
      GROUP BY commune_treize
      ORDER BY moyenne_treize DESC
      LIMIT 3
    )
    
     select  AVG(moyenne_six)::NUMERIC(7,0) as Moyenne_top3_06,
             AVG(moyenne_treize)::NUMERIC(7,0) as Moyenne_top3_13
     from six, treize
```

I am sure there is a way to create a nicer quode, because I have to do the same with 10 averages. I did not find the solutions, but I am sure it exists.
Thank you in advance :).

Comment: Note that your WHERE condition turns your outer join back into an inner join.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but could you elaborate please? What are the implications and do you advice a more efficient way to handle this issue?